# Modificar Canvas em tempo real

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, canvas

Como posso utilizar a *tag* `canvas` do HTML5 e fazer essa alteração em tempo real conforme eu insiro os dados no `input`? Já fiz o `form` e coloquei a `tag canvas` na página. Queria saber se no `JQuery` é possível alterar os dados que insiro no `input` e ao mesmo tempo altere a medida do `canvas`:

**Codigo**:

```
<input type="text"name="largura"/>
<script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var largura = document.getElementById("largura").focus().value;
    var altura = document.getElementById("altura")..focus().value;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(5,5,largura,altura);
</script>
```

Como seria a função no `JQuery` que alteraria essas variáveis em tempo real?

Comment: Tipo o que você gostaria de alterar? Tamanhos? Cor? Posição?

Comment: Opa Fernando, valew pela atençao! Eu queria alterar o tamanho por enquanto. Quero na verdade alterar todo a estrutura do canvas, porém para iniciar eu queria saber como alterar a largura e altura do retangulo. Mas teria que ser ocorrer conforme o valor fosse digitado no input.

Comment: Só um comentário, isto tá errado  `document.getElementById("altura")..focus().value;` o corretor é `document.getElementById("altura").focus().value;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, você pode fazer isso no evento `keyup` como no exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // Ao carregar a página
    $(this).on('keyup', 'input.canvas-settings', function(event){ // Ao soltar a tecla no input
        // Canvas.css( atributo data-prop do input, valor do input)
        $("canvas").css($(this).data('prop'), this.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Largura: <input type="text" data-prop="width" class="canvas-settings" value="100"><br>
Altura: <input type="text" data-prop="height" class="canvas-settings" value="100"><br>
<canvas height="100" width="100" style="border:1px solid red"></canvas>
```

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3nq09ps/)

Comment: KaduAmaral acho que era isso mesmo que eu queria. Porém ainda ficou a dúvida com isso eu altero a medida do canvas, mas como altero o preenchimento que no caso esta sendo feito via javascript ctx.fillRect(5,5,largura,altura);? Mas valew pela ajuda, já me deu uma luz.

Comment: Eu fiz um outro [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otnswh1q/1/), ai eu acho que está apenas redesenhando por cima, não está mudando o tamanho, tanto que quando coloco um tamanho inferior ele não muda. Eu nunca trabalhei com Canvas, então nessa questão não vou poder te ajudar muito @JacielPlacidino. Mas o jQuery é simples...

Comment: voce  me ajudou muito mesmo, eu só tinha dúvida quanto a replicar os valores do input dos campos em outro local da pagina. Brigadão!

Comment: Valeu @JacielPlacidino, precisando estamos aqui. Se a resposta respondeu sua pergunta, marque ela como aceita do lado esquerdo, para que o tópico seja fechado.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
Largura: <input type="text" class="canvas-attr" id="largura" value="100"/><br/>
Altura: <input type="text" class="canvas-attr" id="altura" value="100"/><br/>
<canvas id="c" height="100" width="100" style="border:1px solid red"></canvas>
```

**JQuery**

```
// Quando a largura ou a altura forem alteradas
$(".canvas-attr").on('change',function() {
    // Muda a largura e a altura do canvas
    var c = $("#c");
    c.attr("width",$("#largura").val());
    c.attr("height", $("#altura").val());

    // Cria variáveis com os valores de altura e largura
    var ctx = c[0].getContext("2d");
    var largura = $("#largura").val();
    var altura = $("#altura").val();

    // Cor vermelha para o preenchimento
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    // Colore o canvas inteiro
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,largura,altura);
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieloshiro/eawmd538/)

Comment: Oi GabrielOshiro... Essa é com certeza uma opção muito boa. Mas ainda continuo com a dúvida se e consigo passar esse parametro para o javascript `ctx.fillRect(5,5,largura,altura);`

Comment: @JacielPlacidino Tá aí, modifiquei um pouco para ficar mais próximo do que você pediu

Comment: Eu testei e ficou perfeito. Obrigado! @GabrielOshiro!

Comment: @JacielPlacidino A melhor maneira de me agradecer é com um positivo ;-)

Comment: Ressuscitando o tópico :D é possível fazer essa modificação e a pessoa de um outro computador ver essa modificação em tempo real sem ter a necessidade de atualizar a página, ou seja, ver o canvas sendo alterado?

Comment: @Fox.11 Essa é outra pergunta, eu sugiro que você abra um novo tópico para descrição com o seu código e seu progresso. Vc vai ter mais chances de conseguir uma resposta do que só postar aqui.